# SharePoint 2013 Search Service to index Office 365 Shared Mailbox

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365

I have a project which requires SharePoint 2013 Search Service (on premise deployment) to index one Office 365 Shared Mailbox.
Based on my research the following is **not** possible:

- Exchange content source: it works with old on premise Exchanges
- eDiscovery: This is different feature. It has Exchange configuration
  but can’t be used in Search scenarios.
- Business Connectivity Services:I tried creating external content
  source in Visual Studio providing OData urls but didn’t succeed
- Hybrid federated search works in scenario SharePoint Server 2013 to
  SharePoint Online, not in my scenario
- Third part solution is not accessible by my client.

[This post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7731/what-options-for-indexing-exchange-mailboxes-with-sharepoint) is close to my scenario but it is old and doesn’t lead to solution.

I explored also the new “Groups” in O365 but this is not applicable. My client needs single place for searching SharePoint data and this Shared Mailbox.

What I see as the only possible approach is the use of the [Outlook Rest API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/use-outlook-rest-api) for real time searches against this Mailbox. I tested it and I’m able to retrieve data in SharePoint hosted app. The big problem is that I don’t have refinements and total items count.

Can someone point me to a better solution? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the Microsoft Graph REST instead of Office 365 REST API.

It exposes multiple APIs from Microsoft cloud services through a single REST API endpoint (https://graph.microsoft.com). Using the Microsoft Graph, you can turn formerly difficult or complex queries into simple navigations.

The Microsoft Graph gives you:

- A unified API endpoint for accessing aggregated data from multiple
  Microsoft cloud services in a single response
- Seamless navigation between entities and the relationships among them
- Access to intelligence and insights coming from the Microsoft cloud

And you can use **$count** query parameters to return the number of items in the collection. Here is an example that return the number of result for your reference:

```
GET: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=contains(subject,'a')&$count=true
```

You could get the resonpnse like below for the number of  items:

```
@odata.context=https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('')/messages
@odata.count=341
@odata.nextLink=https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=contains(subject,'a')&$count=true&$skip=10
value{}
```

Comment: Both APIs seems to work in the same way but I will further explore the Microsoft Graph API.
Here are also more details how I query the shared mailbox:1. Register in Azure AD an app; 2. Grant it with permissions to access mails 3. Then the web request uses its ClientID and Secret and the query is like this: https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users('mailbox@domain.onmicrosoft.com')/messages